# change image to other images using javascript and repeat it from last to the first image

Tags: javascript

i want a javascript/html code to change on click an image in my page to other images from my source file and do it repeatedly(when the last image is shown go [on click]to the first image again) without refresh.

Comment: Great. Do some research, find a library, write some code.

Comment: Do you care to share what you've tried? I'm certain you didn't come here to get someone else to write your code without trying, right?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
function change(obj{
    if(obj.src=='images/series0.jpg')
     obj.src='images/series1.jpg';
    else
     obj.src='images/series0.jpg';
    }
</script> I have this javasript

Comment: What is not working or insufficient with your current solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like below to accomplish this though there are numerous ways to do it.  The easiest way to do this is probably to have your image names be identical aside from an incrementing variable, but that is up to you.

```
<img id="myImage" src="image.jpg"/>
<input type="button" onclick="changeImage();" value="Change Image"/>
<script>
  //This array holds all my image paths (hardcoded)
  var images=new Array();
    images[0]="myImage.jpg";
    images[1]="myImage2.jpg";
    images[2]="myThirdImage.jpg";
  var counter=0;

  function changeImage(){
    //Change image and increment counter
    document.getElementById("myImage").src=images[counter++ % images.length];
  }
</script>
```

Also, it depends on how you want this feature to function (image with left/right arrows that circle through a list of images).

EDIT: thanks to [Fizz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/278447/fizz) for the mod suggestion.

Comment: This is a viable solution. Although for the counter reset, you can use the modulus operator to simplify things.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?  I'm not seeing how modulus comes into play here (at least in a simpler manner than specified).

Comment: David Starkey i want to change an image on my page to others (on image click) not with a button.

Comment: Instead of using counter++ your could just use (counter % images.length) and then increment counter. This way you don't need any check to see if counter is greater then the length of the images array.

Comment: And also start over the function without refreshing the page.

Comment: `onclick` is not restricted to buttons.  `"The onclick attribute can be used within ALL HTML elements, EXCEPT: <base>, <bdo>, <br>, <head>, <html>, <iframe>, <meta>, <param>, <script>, <style>, and <title>."` - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: Fizz, that is brilliant.  I had never seen that before, thanks for sharing the info.

Comment: @DavidStarkey Starkey it works with the button but i want to click on the image and change to others.How the html code goes??<a href="#"><img src="images/series0.jpg" width="230" height="250" alt="" onclick="changeImage();" ></a>.I put this but it doesn't work.Thanks for the help both of you by the way.

Comment: Remove the `<a href="#">` and `</a>`  the image doesn't need to be a link